# How to keep whatever is inside a specific title of tag until the next same tag

Tags: r, xml2

Input

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("<h1>keep </h1> also here <li> remove this tag </li> and <h1> this </h1>", "one more example <h1> false alarm </h1> another one <h1>not this</h1>"))
```

How is it possible to keep whatever is after the tag "`<h1>keep </h1>`? I mean check which h1 has the keep or false alarm text inside the tag and keep whatever is after this tag until the next `<h1>` tag.

Example output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("<h1>keep </h1> also here <li> remove this tag </li> and", "one more example <h1> false alarm </h1> another one"))
```